# rank function in vba syntax error

Tags: excel, vba, rank

```
Range("AQ3").Formula = "=IF(ISNA(RANK(N3,Range("N3:N" & lastRow),0)),"",COUNTIF(Range("N3:N" & lastRow)" > "&N3)+1)"
Range("N3:N" & lastRow).filldown
```

Hi, for some reason I keep getting syntax error on the first line.
I already defined last row in the previous section so there should be no error regarding that but i think it has to do something with general syntax.
Can anyone help?
Thanks

Comment: Your Range function is inside of your string -- I don't think that is your intention.

Answer (score 0):

It is because of `"N3:N"` within the formula text. You haven't escaped the double quotes by using `""N3:N""`, for example.

There are general issues with the formula, however, which will stop this from working regardless. What you will require instead:

```
Range("AQ3").Formula = "=IF(ISNA(RANK(N3,N3:N" & lastRow & ",0)),"""",COUNTIF(N3:N" & lastRow & ", "">$N3"")+1)"
Range("N3:N" & lastRow).FillDown
```

You *might* also need to fill down `Range("AQ3:AQ" & lastRow)` – still, this won't throw a runtime error so long as lastRow is a valid integer.

Comment: Just wondering but this code takes too much time to process data with many, many rows (ex 70k rows in excel). is there any way to make this code more efficient?

Comment: I'd have to have a playaround.